# What shares a universe with Planetary?

Tags: comics, dc, planetary

After reading some Planetary, references are made to other groups that apparently actually have written works (The Authority, S.T.O.R.M. Watch, etc.). After doing some *more* reading about the universe, it's a nice and confusing twist of ownership, imprints, and universes.

What comics officially share a universe with Planetary (both past and present, as I understand some things have been exchanged and made part of reboots and such)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Warren Ellis' [*Stormwatch*](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/StormWatch_Vol_1_37) and [*Authority*](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Authority_Vol_1) runs (pre New 52) definitely do. Stormwatch and Authority both feature [Jenny Sparks](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Jennifer_Sparks_%28Earth-50%29), who was born on January 1, 1900 and is a Century Baby like Elijah Snow. The Authority later stars [Jenny Quantum](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Jennifer_Quarx_%28Earth-50%29), Sparks' heir for the 21st century. The Authority's base of operations, a Shiftship, is also featured prominently in an issue of *Planetary*.

The DC Wiki designates entries on all of these characters with [Earth-50](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Earth-50), and gives a list of the titles that are designated as taking place there. That's probably more or less accurate, but seeing as how "Earth-50" started out being owned by Image and then went on to become WildStorm for DC, it's probably not as cut and dry as that list. I would be inclined to say that only the Earth-50 series that directly reference Planetary are canon (those being Authority and Stormwatch).

Answer (score 1):

[Wildcats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcats_%28comics%29) is set in that universe as well.